# SVN patch deletes all my parent folders when directory structure empty

Tags: git, svn, patch

I am trying to use sparse checkout mechanism instead of fetching all trunk.
I have seen an issue when applying patch in svn.Where I did svn move operation.
Where my project named ProjectK has lot folder in the trunk, I would pull only folder AAA from inside trunk

Folder structure
**ProjectK:**

```
AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/abc.txt
AAA/child1/child2/text12.txt
AAA/child1/child2/text123.txt
AAA/child111/child222/text123.txt
KKK/JJJ/name.txt
```

Here I want move a file abc.txt from current folder to new folder EEE

1. Created workspace where I pulled latest code from SVN master

   `AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/abc.txt`

STEP1:

`svn co --depth empty svn+ssh://svn@url/ProjectK/trunk workspace123`

STEP2:

```
svn up --parents AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD
A    AAA
A    AAA/BBB
A    AAA/BBB/CCC
Updating 'AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD':
A    AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD
A    AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/abc.txt
```

STEP3: Did SVN move operation

```
svn mv abc.txt EEE
A         EEE/abc.txt
D         abc.txt
```

STEP4: Created patch file

```
svn diff --patch-compatible > new_patch.patch
```

STEP5: Pulled latest SVN master before applying patch

```
svn checkout --depth empty svn+ssh://url/ProjectK//trunk .

svn up --parents AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD
```

STEP6: Applying patch for latest code

```
svn patch new_patch.patch

D         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/abc.txt
D         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD
D         AAA/BBB/CCC
D         AAA/BBB
D         AAA
A         AAA
A         AAA/BBB
A         AAA/BBB/CCC
A         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD
A         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/EEE
A         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/EEE/abc.txt
```

After applying patch all folders inside my folder AAA got deleted instead of AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD, what I am doing wrong here?

```
Replacing      AAA
Adding         AAA/BBB
Adding         AAA/BBB/CCC
Adding         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD
Adding         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/EEE
Adding         AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/EEE/abc.txt
Transmitting file data .done
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the correctness of `new_patch.patch`?

Comment: @Friedrich Yes, checked. Not seen any issue with that. When applying a patch if there is any empty directory hierarchy it deletes the entire structure